# Do not display the correct site on Ipad

Tags: html, css

I ask again for your help. Go to this [link](http://partssystem.ru/) and take a look at this block, which is the screenshot.

[image]

All displayed smoothly and accurately.The following screenshot shows the display on the Ipad

[image]

As you can see, the block has moved. The code seems correct, I do not understand what was happening. Please help

Comment: i think view problem of html element. plz make sure different CSS for ipad.

Comment: How do I do? That is, I need to create a separate css file for the Ipad? How to bind a file to html, so that it only worked for the Ipad?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use [media queries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/Media_queries/) to target specific devices and apply relevant styling.

```
/* iPads (portrait and landscape) ----------- */
@media only screen 
and (min-device-width : 768px) 
and (max-device-width : 1024px) {
/* Styles */
}

/* iPads (landscape) ----------- */
@media only screen 
and (min-device-width : 768px) 
and (max-device-width : 1024px) 
and (orientation : landscape) {
/* Styles */
}

/* iPads (portrait) ----------- */
@media only screen 
and (min-device-width : 768px) 
and (max-device-width : 1024px) 
and (orientation : portrait) {
/* Styles */
}
```

Source : http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/media-queries-for-standard-devices/